# Any option in Liferay to intact the site level changes while using site template?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am working on a POC for site templates and sites. I am able to get the propagation of the changes from the site template to the site, but there is something that seems to be un-comforting:

What I am doing here:

1. I created a site template, and added say a blog, navigation,
   calender to it.
2. I created a site named A which is using the
   aforementioned site template.. thus I can see those above configured
   applications in site A.
3. Now I added some site A level apps like
   wiki, and polls.

Now, I get a message that says "Reset changes" (as the site changes are not same as its template). So I did a reset and all site level changes like wiki and polls are lost.

I know we can disable propagation of these changes, post site creation, but we have a requirement as per which we need to update content in the site template, which should be propagated, to all the sites using that template, ensuring all the site level changes are intacted.

**Question:**

Is there a way wherein we can sustain the site level changes, along with the new changes in the site template (reset does not seems to be working as per this requirement)?

Note: We are looking for an out-of-the-box solution from Liferay, before jumping to any customization (but any idea on would be welcomed).

Liferay version :  Liferay Portal Community Edition 6.2 CE GA2 (Newton / Build 6201 / March 20, 2014)

Any pointer would be a great help.

Cheers!!
AJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem with a project I am working on.  The main drawback of site templates with propagation is exactly what you describe - any changes on the child sites can be wiped out by this propagation.

I took an approach that utilizes OOTB liferay features but requires development work for changes by embedded portlets into page layouts.  You can also embed some basic portlet configuration in layouts as well.  Here's a snippet from one of the layouts we are using:

```
#set($customTitlePreference = "<preference><name>portletSetupUseCustomTitle</name><value>true</value></preference>")
#set($noBorderPreference = "<preference><name>portletSetupShowBorders</name><value>false</value></preference>")

#set($basicPreferences = "<portlet-preferences>${customTitlePreference}${noBorderPreference}</portlet-preferences>")

<div class="three_columns" id="main-content" role="main">
    <div class="portlet-layout">
        <div class="portlet-column portlet-column-first" id="row-1-column-1">
            $theme.runtime("85", "", "${basicPreferences}")
            $theme.runtime("56_INSTANCE_RELATED", "", "${basicPreferences}")
            $processor.processColumn("row-1-column-1", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-first")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is only the first column, but it shows a site map (pid 85) and a web content display with a specified instanceId (pid 56).  This is the first of three columns, and this technique folds seamlessly into all layout components.

Each page can have its own layout, or you can re-use layouts across different pages.  Any updates to the layouts that are deployed to the server will propagate to each page using the layout but not destroy the customizations made to the pages.  The only functional downside to this is that portlets can only be added to the bottom of each column, as the embedded portlets will be rendered first.  You can circumvent this by being clever with rows and columns in your layouts.